# Android Gridview show without text string

Tags: android, gridview

I use this tutorial:
[Tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html)

To show me a image into gridview,very good,but this tutorial show me image and text for example google but i want just show me image,and when i delete this line on code:

```
public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.Imageid = Imageid;
    this.web = web;
}
```

i delete the `String[] web` but when i run my app is crash and exit the program.
How can i delete the text on gridview and just show to me image?

Comment: what errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do the changes mention by **Dhruti** after that try these, If you do not want title strings means remove this constructor

```
public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.Imageid = Imageid;
          this.web = web;
      }
```

and change like below

```
public CustomGrid(Context c,int[] Imageid ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.Imageid = Imageid;
      }
```

Change  `adapter's` `getView()` like below,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View grid;
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
          } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
          }
      return grid;
    }
```

Comment: I write your code but when remove the String[] web,they have a this error:the blank final web may be not initialized

Comment: just remove `private final String[] web;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove text, so you should remove it firstly from your layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="9sp" >
</TextView>
```

Remove this. and all references to `grid_text` from java code, too.

Even after that if you get crash, show logcat.